# Why 'excedances' of permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, permutations

For a permutation $\pi=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n$ written in one-line notation, an index $i$ for which $\pi_i > i$ is usually called an 'excedance.' To me, this seems like a mispelling of what should be 'exceedance': [many](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exceedance) [dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exceedance) [list](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/exceedance) 'exceedance' as a valid word, but none I can find consider 'excedance' a correct spelling of any word. Also, as far as I know, 'excedance' is pronounced like 'exceedance' (that is, ex-ceed-ance). But, while both ['excedance'](https://www.google.com/search?q=excedance%20permutation) and ['exceedance'](https://www.google.com/search?q=exceedance%20permutation) are to some extent used for this permutation concept, it seems that 'excedance' is much more common.

**Question**: Does anyone know the origin of the spelling 'excedance' for this permutation concept? Is it an error which has become standard?

Comment: Sounds like a bad translation of either Latin or the French [excédence](//www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/excédence).

Comment: You could ask linguists.

Comment: Although your reputation indicates you know the spirit of the site better than I do, it's hard for me to understand in what sense this is a question about research mathematics.

Comment: I've seen questions here before about terminology, but if this is deemed inappropriate for the site I would understand that as well.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excedance explicitly lists excedance as a misspelling of exceedance.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable deviation and diversion from the forum scope.  Gerhard "Don't Do It Again Soon" Paseman, 2020.05.08.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: interestingly that page has now been edited to list excedance as the correct spelling of the mathematical concept.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

*Mea culpa.* Comtet used the term *excédence*. When writing EC1 I needed an English term for this concept. For some reason I didn't like the word exceedance. I thought it looked better without the double e, analogous to proceed and procedure. Thus I made up the word *excedance*.

Comment: Couldn't imagine a more authoritative response. Thanks!

Comment: It looks better to me too without the double e, but that might be because I've gotten used to it.