# Is there a lop-sided permutation $\pi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory, permutations, infinite-combinatorics

For any $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we let the (lower) density of $A$ be defined by $$d(A) = \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{0,\ldots,n\}|}{n+1}.$$
If $\pi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a permutation (bijection), let $\text{ex}(\pi) = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: \pi(n) > n\}$ be the set of [*exceedances*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359684/why-excedances-of-permutations), and let $\text{negex}(\pi)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \pi(n) < n\}$ be the set of "negative exceedances".

To me it seems inconceivable that there is a permutation $\pi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $d\big(\text{ex}(\pi)\big) \neq d\big(\text{negex}(\pi)\big)$ -- but my intuition has let me down many times.

Is my intuition correct this time? ${}$

Comment: Terminological point: what you call $\mathrm{pos}(\pi)$ is usually called the set of excedances of the permutation $\pi$ (see also my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359684 )

Comment: I mean, both of them definitely can be zero. Is this good enough for you?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $d\big(\text{pos}(\pi)\big) \neq d\big(\text{neg}(\pi)\big)$ is inconceivable?

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll correct it in the next couple minutes.

Comment: Of course @gro-tsen --> will correct!

Comment: Still, slight modification of the (already deleted) comments gives us this: if on each group of 4 consecutive elements we have rotation by 1 position. Then one limit is $\frac{3}{4}$ and the other one is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Wouldn't $(1)(23)(4567)(8, 9, 10 ,11 ,12, 13, 14, 15)...$ be such a permutation? (Add 1 if it isn't one less than a power of two, add 1 and halve if it is). It has $d(pos(\pi)) = 1$ and $d(neg(\pi))=0$

Comment: **Apologies** for missing the $\neq$ sign and putting the $=$ sign instead in the original version. Of course I mean a permutation to be *lop-sided* if there are more excedences than... "negative excedences", or the other way round.

Comment: If $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ into two infinite sets with $1\in A$, then there is a permutation $\pi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $A=\{n:\pi(n)\gt n\}$ and $B=\{n:\pi(n)\lt n\}$. Namely, write $A=\{a_1\lt a_2\lt a_2\lt\cdots\}$ and $B=\{b_1\lt b_2\lt b_3\lt\cdots\}$ and define $\pi(a_n)=a_{n+1}$ and $\pi(b_{n+1}=b_n$ for all $n\ge1$, and $\pi(b_1)=1=a_1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\pi(n) = n+1$ for all $n$ except that $\pi(2^{k}-1) = 2^{k-1}$.  In other words, permute cyclically $(2,3)$, $(4,5,6,7)$, $(8,9,10,\ldots,15)$, and so on.  Then $d(\operatorname{pos}(\pi))=1$ whereas $d(\operatorname{neg}(\pi))=0$.

Comment: Ah, it seems that Command Master came up with the same answer (in the comments) as I was typing this one.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453494/is-there-a-lop-sided-permutation-pi-mathbbn-to-mathbbn#comment1173171_453495), @CommandMaster's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453494/is-there-a-lop-sided-permutation-pi-mathbbn-to-mathbbn#comment1173169_453494). Perhaps the acknowledgement could go in the main post?

Comment: What I find extra counter-intuitive about @Gro-Tsen's and CommandMaster's construction is, that $\pi^{-1}$ has the property that $d\big(\text{ex}(\pi^{-1})\big) = 0 < 1 = d\big(\text{negex}((\pi^{-1})\big)$. Counterintuitive, because "below every natural number there are only finitely many naturals, but above infinitely many".